# Varnish probe always returning sick backend

Tags: apache, virtualhost, varnish, varnish-vcl

I have Varnish running on port 80 and Apache running on port 8088 on the same machine (I'm using it for development/testing).

Apache is defined as the backend in VCL as follows:

```
backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8088";
    .first_byte_timeout = 600s;
    .probe = {
        .request = "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1"
                "Host: example.com"
                "Connection: close";
        .interval = 5s;
        .timeout = 1s;
        .window = 10;
        .threshold = 8;
    }
}
```

As you can see I have a probe set up. However, when I do varnishadm backend.list I get

```
Backend name                   Refs   Admin      Probe
default(127.0.0.1,,8088)       1      probe      Sick 0/10
```

When I execute wget 127.0.0.1:8088 I get

```
--2017-04-17 10:20:20--  http://127.0.0.1:8088/
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:8088... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: http://magento2.dev/?SID=obcv7ifsq5b4ro9jr3hmpb7oi4 [following]
--2017-04-17 10:20:20--  http://magento2.dev/?SID=obcv7ifsq5b4ro9jr3hmpb7oi4
Resolving magento2.dev... 127.0.53.53
Connecting to magento2.dev|127.0.53.53|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 503 Backend fetch failed
2017-04-17 10:20:20 ERROR 503: Backend fetch failed.
```

So could it be the probe is receiving a 503 error? Since the request is going to Varnish instead of Apache. Or am I wrong here?

For the record here is my Virtualhost setup for Apache:

```
<VirtualHost *:8088>
     ServerAdmin admin@example.org
     ServerName magento2.dev
     ServerAlias www.magento2.dev
     DocumentRoot "/var/www/magento2/"
         CustomLog /var/log/httpd/magento2.dev-access.log combined
         ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/magento2.dev-error.log
     <Directory "/var/www/magento2/">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
     </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Any ideas appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 7):

A probe is successful if the HTTP status being returned is `200 OK`. Currently your probe gets redirect `302 Found` thus it marks the backend as sick.

You need to make sure that `curl -IL http://127.0.0.1:8088/ -H "magento2.dev"` does not return any redirect. (Magento settings?)

The following command is more useful in troubleshooting sick backends, since it will show you the HTTP status that is returned:

```
varnishlog -g raw -i Backend_health
```